# Django:name 'Post' is not defined in InteractiveConsole

Tags: python, django, nameerror

I am very new to Django, and was trying to develop a blog based on it.

After the commands of `python manage.py makemigrations`  and `python manage.py migrate` worked well, I got into the InteractiveConsole to execute `Post.objects.all()` and got a NameError.

```
>>> Post.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Post' is not defined
```

Besides, when running localhost:8000, Server gave another NameError.

```
NameError at /
name 'Post' is not defined
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 2.0
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'Post' is not defined
Exception Location: D:\experiment\blogproject\blog\views.py in index, line 6
Python Executable:  d:\experiment\blogproject_env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.3
Python Path:    
['D:\\experiment\\blogproject',
'd:\\experiment\\blogproject_env\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
'd:\\experiment\\blogproject_env\\DLLs',
'd:\\experiment\\blogproject_env\\lib',
'd:\\experiment\\blogproject_env\\Scripts',
'd:\\professional soft\\python3.6.3\\Lib',
'd:\\professional soft\\python3.6.3\\DLLs',
'd:\\experiment\\blogproject_env',
'd:\\experiment\\blogproject_env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    星期五, 22 十二月 2017 16:08:10 +0800
```

and the following was my views.py.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    post_list = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created_time')
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context={'post_list': post_list})
```

In case, there is the Post code in models.py.

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)

```
body = models.TextField()

created_time = models.DateTimeField()
modified_time = models.DateTimeField()

excerpt = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)

author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Thank u so much!

Comment: where is the import statement ??  eg. from <app>.models import Post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing your Interactive Shell does not auto import all the required files for you. Before you can start using those non-default method, functions, models, etc you need to import it.

In your case you must import the Post model before using it.

`from app.models import Post`

Where app is the actual app the model is living in.

This also counts for your view, you must import the model before using it.

Comment: i have imported  ` from django.contrib.auth.models import User ` 
Its still showing the same error

Answer (score 0):

You have you import your model in the views.

In your case should be something like:

```
from appName.models import Post
```

Hope this helps!